# should my child classes inherit empty functions from parent class?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to make a parent class and child classes, lets say the parent class is called functionality and has functions like `add()`, `validate()`, and `delete()`, and the child classes are driver and passenger , each of the child classes inherit the functions but needs extra parameters and different logic for each inherited function, should I define the function but leave it blank? how is this helpful apart from extendibility?, and should I define a different constructor for each child class because they have different extra variables?

class functionality

```
class functionality{
    
    protected $from;
    protected $to;
    protected $date;
    protected $name;
    
  public function add(){
      
  }
  
   public function validate(){
      
  }
  
  public function delete(){
      
  }
  
 
}
```

class driver

```
class driver extends functionality {

private $gasMoney

function add($from, $to, $date, $name, $gasMoney){

//some logic and adding to database

}

}
```

class passenger

```
class passenger extends functionality {

private $seatPrefrance

function add($from, $to, $date, $name, $seatPreferance){
//different logic than class driver and 

}

}
```

is this an acceptable approach? and how would I define a constructer? should I define it in the parent class? does the child classes inherit it and can add more to it?

Answer (score 2):

You *shouldn't* use inheritance for this, it doesn't make sense.

The main idea is that other parts of your application can receive an object, and they don't care if it's a `passenger` or `driver`, they just get some instance of `functionality` and call `add` on it.

Another reason to use inheritance if you want to take advantage of some shared behavior, so you don't have to reimplement a method.

If arguments are different based on the sub-class, there's no way anything can do something with the generic `functionality` class, so this is pointless.

You also can't re-use the method, because you are clearly overriding the method for each case.

Think about `driver` and `passenger`. Are there parts in your application that need to work with both? What is their actual common functionality? Anything that's not common does not go in the base class.

I know this is probably a contrived example, but it also doesn't make sense to 'add' a passenger name to an existing passenger.

If you call your class 'passenger', I would expect that to represent a *single* passenger, not multiple.

Comment: "If arguments are different based on the sub-class, there's no way anything can do something with the generic functionality class"... my intention wasn't for the functionality class to be used, it was a way to define hared variables and overridden function so if i want to add another class that extends the functionality class it would be easier

Comment: "Are there parts in your application that need to work with both? What is their actual common functionality? "... they don't have a common code, it was just the idea that both have an inherited function called add() for example that enters data to the database in different ways, or a function validation() that validates data in different ways i'm really bad at this i don't know how to start over, i feel so down

Comment: "it also doesn't make sense to 'add' a passenger name to an existing passenger." i'm not sure if if i understand what you mean but i edited the name, which shouldn't exist in the passenger class alone, but i don't understand what you mean to an existing passenger, the name is used in the function to enter it to the database that's it.

Comment: @hemolNNESS, well let me repeat then. You don't need the `functionality` class. Don't extend from it.

Comment: so i should define each function in each class by it's own if they don't share actual code?

Comment: You are already defining a function with the same name in each class, whether or not you have a base class. Why do you want to add a base class to begin with? It's not about sharing code. You said yourself that each function was going to have different arguments. This means they are not compatible. But the overriding question is why are you adding a base class?

Answer (score -1):

Learn OOP as a tool, not a religion.

If you meet an inspiring preacher, they might teach you a whole new way of thinking about the world, and suddenly you see everything in a new light. You change your diet, your daily routine, and which TV programs you watch.

If you are given a new drill as a present, you might get some **scrape** wood to test it out a few times, but after that you'll wait until you need to put some shelves up. You won't work out how you can pour milk through a newly drilled hole in your breakfast counter.

The example you have come up with is trying to do OOP for OOP's sake. It doesn't make any sense, because you haven't actually got a problem you're trying to solve.

In particular, don't pull out the inheritance drill until you need it. Start off by looking for ways to **encapsulate state** in private properties and **define behaviour** that is more than just accessing that state. As a silly example, `$driver->canLegallyDrive()` method might internally check the `$insurance` and `$alcoholLevel` properties.

Even when you find logic you want to share, **composition** (just storing one object in a private property of another one) is often better than inheritance. Inheritance really comes into its own when you need **polymorphism** - multiple objects which look the same on the outside but behave differently on the inside. And even then, learning to use **interfaces** rather than base classes will unlock more potential.